# All permutations of quartely data

Tags: r, permutation

I have a data set that contains quarterly data for 8 years. If I randomly select each quarter from one of the years I could in theory construct a "new" year. For example: new year = Q1(2009), Q2(2012), Q3(2010), Q4(2015).

The problem I have, is that I would like to construct a data set that contains all such permutations. With 8 years and 4 quarters that would give me 4^8= 65536 "new" years.  Is this something best tackled with a nested loop, or are there functions out there that could work better?

Comment: What you're talking about are not permutations (in the mathematical sense). Read the info for that tag or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html

Comment: @Frank: you are actually correct. I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `expand.grid` to create a matrix of all possible combinations:

```
nrow(do.call('expand.grid', replicate(8, 1:4, simplify=FALSE)))
[1] 65536
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wait a bit to see if someone gives you a less 'janky' answer, but this example takes a time series, takes all permutations with no repeated quarters inside of each year, and returns those new years values with the old year and quarters info as columns.

```
set.seed(1234)

# Make some fake data
q_dat <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2011,4),
                             rep(2012,4),
                             rep(2013,4)),
                    quarters = rep(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),3),
                    x = rnorm(12))
q_dat

   year quarters          x
1  2011       Q1 -1.2070657
2  2011       Q2  0.2774292
3  2011       Q3  1.0844412
4  2011       Q4 -2.3456977
5  2012       Q1  0.4291247
6  2012       Q2  0.5060559
7  2012       Q3 -0.5747400
8  2012       Q4 -0.5466319
9  2013       Q1 -0.5644520
10 2013       Q2 -0.8900378
11 2013       Q3 -0.4771927
12 2013       Q4 -0.9983864
```

So what are going to do is

1, Take all possible combinations of the time series

2, Remove all duplicates so each made up year does not have the same quarter in it.

```
# Expand out all possible combinations of our three years
q_perms <- expand.grid(q1 = 1:nrow(q_dat), q2 = 1:nrow(q_dat) ,
                       q3 = 1:nrow(q_dat), q4 = 1:nrow(q_dat))

# remove any duplicate combinations
# EX: So we don't get c(2011Q1,2011Q1,2011Q1,2011Q1) as a year
q_perms <- q_perms[apply(q_perms,1,function(x) !any(duplicated(x))),]

# Transpose the grid, remake it as a data frame, and lapply over it
l_rand_dat <- lapply(data.frame(t(q_perms)),function(x) q_dat[x,])

# returns one unique year per list
l_rand_dat[[30]]
  year quarters          x
5 2012       Q1  0.4291247
6 2012       Q2  0.5060559
2 2011       Q2  0.2774292
1 2011       Q1 -1.2070657


# bind all of those together
rand_bind <- do.call(rbind,l_rand_dat)

head(rand_bind)

       year quarters          x
X172.4 2011       Q4 -2.3456977
X172.3 2011       Q3  1.0844412
X172.2 2011       Q2  0.2774292
X172.1 2011       Q1 -1.2070657
X173.5 2012       Q1  0.4291247
X173.3 2011       Q3  1.0844412
```

This is a pretty memory intensive answer. If someone can skip the 'make all possible combinations' step then that would be a significant improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm dealing with a fairly large data set, so memory usage may well be an issue, but this gives me a good place to start.

Comment: @PaulGreeley if your data is eight years worth this should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you want combinations of the 8 years over 4 quarters so the number of combinations is 8^4 = 4096:

```
> x <- years <- 2008:2015
> length(x)
[1] 8
> comb <- expand.grid(x, x, x, x)
> head(comb)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1 2008 2008 2008 2008
2 2009 2008 2008 2008
3 2010 2008 2008 2008
4 2011 2008 2008 2008
5 2012 2008 2008 2008
6 2013 2008 2008 2008
> tail(comb)
     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
4091 2010 2015 2015 2015
4092 2011 2015 2015 2015
4093 2012 2015 2015 2015
4094 2013 2015 2015 2015
4095 2014 2015 2015 2015
4096 2015 2015 2015 2015
> nrow(comb)
[1] 4096
```

Each row is a year and Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4 are the 4 quarters.

Comment: No, I think they want one quarter per year, not one year per quarter. That's why they have a larger number than your 4096.